# Multiple events of bloc cubit inside the same screen

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I have screen where i'm fetching data from different api endpoints , when i try to call both in the same , it loads one of the two requests , either the first or the second , not able to load them both , any reason why , Thank you .

- Splash Screen where i call both states before moving on to home screen

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 7),(){
      BlocProvider.of<NewsCubit>(context).getEverything('sport');
      BlocProvider.of<NewsCubit>(context).getHeadlines();
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset('assets/gifs/news.gif',),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- This is Home Screen where i'm upading the ui

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:news_app_flutter/cubit/app_cubit.dart';
import 'package:news_app_flutter/cubit/app_cubit_state.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  final _searchKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final _queries = [
    'Health',
    'Sport',
    'Politics',
    'Economy',
    'Education'
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding:  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20,left: 20,right: 20),
          child:  Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Form(
                key: _searchKey,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _searchController,
                  validator: (value){
                    if(value!.isEmpty){
                      return 'Please write something';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                     contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 10),
                      hintText: 'search',
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,fontFamily: 'nunito_regular'),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black45),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                      ),
                      suffixIcon:  IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          var isSearchEditValidated = _searchKey.currentState!.validate();
                          if(isSearchEditValidated){
                             BlocProvider.of<NewsCubit>(context).getEverything(_searchController.text);
                          }
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.black54,size: 20,),)
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              const Text('Latest News',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'nunito_bold'),),
              const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              SizedBox(
                width: 350,
                height: 250,
                child :  BlocBuilder<NewsCubit,NewsState>(
                  builder: (context , state){
                    if(state is HeadlinesState){
                      var news = state.headlineData;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: news!.articles!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context , index){
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              BlocProvider.of<NewsCubit>(context).getDetails(news.articles![index]);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    child: news.articles![index].urlToImage != null ? Image.network(news.articles![index].urlToImage!,fit: BoxFit.cover,) :
                                    Container(),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    top: 50,
                                    left : 30,
                                    child: Text(news.articles![index].author == null ? 'by N/A' : 'by ${news.articles![index].author!}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'nunito_semi'),) ,
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    top: 80,
                                    left: 30,
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                        width : 300,
                                        child: Text(news.articles![index].title!,style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'nunito_bold'),maxLines: 2,)),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    bottom: 10,
                                    left: 30,
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width : 300,
                                      child: Text(news.articles![index].content!,maxLines: 2,style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 13,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        fontFamily: 'nunito_semi'
                                       ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (state is LoadingState){
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.black87,),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.black87,),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.maxFinite,
                height: 40,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: _queries.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          gradient: const LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                Color(0xFFFF3A44),
                                Color(0xFFFF8086),
                              ],
                              stops: [1.0, 0.0],
                              begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                              end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                              tileMode: TileMode.clamp
                          )
                      ),
                      child: Center(child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20,left: 20),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            BlocProvider.of<NewsCubit>(context).getEverything(_queries[index]);
                          },
                          child: Text(_queries[index],style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'nunito_bold'),),
                        ),
                      )),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 15,),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 350,
                  height: 150,
                  child :  BlocBuilder<NewsCubit,NewsState>(
                    builder: (context , state){
                      if(state is LoadedState){
                        var news = state.newsModel;
                        return ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: news!.articles!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context , index){
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                BlocProvider.of<NewsCubit>(context).getDetails(news.articles![index]);
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                      child: Image.network(news.articles![index].urlToImage!,fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                                    ),
                                    Positioned(
                                      top: 10,
                                      left: 20,
                                      right : 20,
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                          width : 350,
                                          child: Text(news.articles![index].title!,style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 17,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'nunito_bold'),maxLines: 2)),
                                    ),
                                    Positioned(
                                      bottom: 10,
                                      left: 20,
                                      right : 20,
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Flexible(
                                            child: Text(news.articles![index].author == null ? 'by N/A' : 'by ${news.articles![index].author}',
                                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'nunito_semi'),),
                                          ),
                                          Text(formatDate(news.articles![index].publishedAt!),style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                          fontFamily: 'nunito_semi'),)
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else if (state is LoadingState){
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.black87,),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.black87,),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String formatDate(String date){
    DateFormat dt1 = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ');
    DateTime dtime = dt1.parse(date);
    DateFormat dt2 = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
    return dt2.format(dtime);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the API calls are async, you not waiting for first call to complete before making the second call. As cubits can hold a single global state, the api call to complete last will overwrite the result of first api call. It is just like a race condition where the last one to finish will overwrite the result of the first one.

Solution: a simple solution is to await the calls (or atleast the first api call).

Another problem i see is a cubit can stay in only one state at a given time. So you can't expect it to stay in both HeadlineState and LoadedState, you might have to replace those if checks with something else (a null check on specific field of the state that holds the result may be)

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 7),() async {
  await BlocProvider.of<NewsCubit>(context).getEverything('sport');
  BlocProvider.of<NewsCubit>(context).getHeadlines();
});
```

If you can post the code of NewsCubit, i may be able to think of better solution

Comment: Upon doing that , it shows message that bloc should not be used in async functions , on the other hand i did try to set both requestions in initState of home screen , what i noticed is that when the first one is done , after few seconds i trigger the second request ,  when the second one triggers  , it triggers also the first request ..

Comment: Please the share code of NewsCubit